# How to find exact solution of this volterra equation?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, integral-equations

I was working on numerical solution of this equation (by block pulse). 
$$x(t)=1+\int_{0}^{t}s^2x(s)ds+\int_{0}^{t}sx(s)dB(s)\\t \in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$$B(t) is standard brownian motion.
Author of the paper said :the exact solution of this equation is **$$ x(t)=e^{\frac{t^3}{6}+\int_{0}^{t}sdB(s)}$$** I tried to check the exact solution into it ,.I tried to  find the exact solution ,but I can't.please help me to understand how obtain this exact solution (or check into equation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y_t = \int_0^ts\,dB_s$. Note that $Y$ is a martingale and hence a semimartingale. Then consider the process $X_t = f(t,Y_t)$ with $f(t,x) = e^{\frac{t^3}{6}+x}$. Since the partial derivatives $f_t,f_x,f_{xx}$ all exist and are continuous, Ito's lemma applies in this situation.
$$f(t,Y_t) = f(0,Y_0) + \int_0^tf_t(s,Y_s)\,ds + \int_0^tf_x(s,Y_s)\,dY_s + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^tf_{xx}(s,Y_s)\,d[Y,Y]_s$$
It is easy to compute that $[Y,Y]_t = \int_0^ts^2\,ds = \frac{t^3}{3}$. Furthermore, $dY_s = s\,dB_s$ and $X_0 = f(0,Y_0) = 1$.
Putting everything together
$$X_t = X_0 + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^ts^2X_s\,ds + \int_0^tsX_s\,dB_s + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^ts^2X_s\,ds = 1 + \int_0^tsX_s\,dB_s + \int_0^ts^2X_s\,ds$$

To show $[Y,Y]_t = \int_0^ts^2\,ds$, I used the following result.

> For semimartingales $M,N$
>   $$[\int G_sdM_s,\int H_sdN_s]_t = \int_{(0,t]}G_sH_s\,d[M,N]_s$$

Comment: I had a type,I fix it ,$\frac{t^3}{3} \to \frac{t^3}{6}$ but do not make a big difference .Thank You .Can you explain ( abit more)how to compute $[y,y]t$ ?--do you use Ito Isometery formula ?

Comment: @Khosrotash You are welcome. I edited my answer. Ito isometry is not relevant here.

Comment: Ok.I got it . thank you very much

Comment: @Khosrotash No problem. If my post answers your question, I would appreciate it if you could accept it.